# Остановить Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol, storyboard

Имеется юзерконтрол, который имеет поля имя, онлайн и т.д. Когда собеседник начинает печатать, приходит LongPoll ответ. Далее срабатывает метод, который ищет этот контрол и присваивает свойству IsTyping значение true, срабатывает Storyboard, который заменяет поле сообщение на "Is typing...". Как мне по истечении 5 секунд вернуть поле сообщение в исходное?

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StringAnimationStoryboard">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames AutoReverse="False"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="MessageTextBlock"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text"
                                   Duration="5">
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Is typing." KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Is typing.." KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Is typing..." KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Is typing...." KeyTime="0:0:0.7" />
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTyping}" Value="true">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource StringAnimationStoryboard}"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Покажите код...

Comment: Добавил код....

Comment: `<DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="" KeyTime="0:0:5" />` — не подходит?

Comment: Просто пустым оставить? Значение туда не вставить, ибо там биндинг

Comment: А у вас там что-то до "Is typing" отображается?

Comment: А у вас `IsTyping` в `false` не возвращается? Если возвращается, можно попробовать в `ExitActions` удалить анимацию. Если не возвращается, то почему?

Comment: Вариант с `<DataTrigger.ExitActions><RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginStoryboard"/></DataTrigger.ExitActions>` точно рабочий, проверил у себя.

Comment: IsTyping в false не возвращается потому, что не приходит повторный лонгпулл о том, что юзер перестал печатать.Т.е. только путём таймера я должен обратно false ставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените в `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` значение свойства `Duration` на `0:0:5` (у вас сейчас стоит просто `5` — это 5 дней) и задайте значение `FillBehavior="Stop"` (по умолчанию там `HoldEnd`), тогда по завершении анимации она автоматически удалится и вступит в силу значение из привязки.

Другой способ (даже при использовании первого этот может оказаться тоже нужным) — удалять анимацию при обратном срабатывании триггера:

```
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginStoryboard"/>
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
```

Comment: Да, благодарю! Теперь всё работает!) Скорее всего ошибка была в Duration.Для повторения только копипаст использовать? Или есть свойство, чтобы в рамках Duration анимация повторялась?

Comment: Посмотрите свойство RepeatBehaviorу анимации